# Help converting to subroutine

Tags: perl

I have tried to convert my code into a series of subroutines to make it more modular. The conditional statements in the code below is what I can't incorporate into the subroutine.

```
next unless ( $sentblock =~ /\[sent. \d+ len. \d+\]: \[.+\]/ );               #1#
( $sentence, $sentencenumber ) = &sentence_sentnum_chptnum($sentblock); #SUBROUTINE
if ( $sentence =~ /\~\s(\d*F*[\.I_]\w+)\s/ ) {                                #2#
    $chapternumber = $1;
    $chapternumber =~ tr/./_/;
}
next
  unless ( $sentence =~ /\b\Q$search_key\E/i                                  #3#
    && $sentence =~ /\b\Q$addkey0\E/i
    && $sentence =~ /\b\Q$addkey1\E/i );
next
  if ( defined($exc0)                                                         #4#
    && length($exc0)
    && $sentence =~ /\b\Q$exc0\E\b/i );
next
  if ( defined($exc1)                                                         #5#
    && length($exc1)
    && $sentence =~ /\b\Q$exc1\E\b/i );
```

The subroutine so far:

```
sub sentence_sentnum_chptnum {
    my $subsentblock = shift;
    my ( $subsentence, $subsentencenumber );
    return unless ( $subsentblock =~ /\[sent. (\d+) len. \d+\]: \[(.+)\]/ ); #DIDN'T replace the need to put one in the main script
    $subsentencenumber = $1;
    $subsentence       = $2;
    $subsentence =~ s/, / /g;
    return ( $subsentence, $subsentencenumber );
}
```

It works as is, but if I try putting the other conditional statements in: I get errors saying `$sentence is uninitialized` later in the code. Example: If I try to include the check of `$addkey` using the same condition, but just swapping `next` for `return` I get an error that `$sentence is uninitialized` in the line: `if ( $sentence =~ /\~\s(\d*F*[\.I_]\w+)\s/ ) {` And likewise if I put any of those conditions into the subroutine.

**Main Question:** How can I:

(1) get rid of `next unless ( $sentblock =~ /\[sent. \d+ len. \d+\]: \[.+\]/ );` (it's in the subroutine too)

(2) Include: `if ( $sentence =~ /\~\s(\d*F*[\.I_]\w+)\s/ )` & all 3 `next` statements

(3) Since it's included, also return `$chapternumber`

Without affecting my code?

**General Best Practice Question:**  If I have variables defined at the top of my code (from an HTML form) is it better practice to localize them each time in every subroutine, or just not pass anything into the subroutine, and use the value assigned at the beginning of the code? (Ex. `$search_key`, `$addkey` and `$exc`)?

**Test Case** I have made a test case, however it is pretty long, so I didn't include it. If you need one, it is very similar to: http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=912276 just find where the subroutine takes over and delete that part... It's right after `foreach my $sentblock (@parsed)`.

Note: The test case does not include `addkey` or `exc`, and nothing will match the chapternumber (put '~ 5.5' in front of one sentence to include it)

**I've tried** checking the returned `$sentence` in the main program. This eliminates the error, but there are no matches for the rest of the program (ie. The end result of the search engine is 0 results).

Thanks, let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: I won't be much help as I'm limited to my iPhone right now but +1 for one of the most well-asked questions I've ever seen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How much do you want to break things down?  It's hard to see what the "best" or "right" way to split things up is without more code.

In general, if you go through your code and add comments describing what each block of code does, you could just as readily replace each commented block with a sub that has a name that recaps the sentence:

```
# Is this a sentence block?
next unless ( $sent_block =~ /\[sent. \d+ len. \d+\]: \[.+\]/ );    
           #1#

my ( $sentence, $sentence_number ) = parse_sentence_block($sent_block);

# Get chapter info if present
if ( $sentence =~ /\~\s(\d*F*[\.I_]\w+)\s/ ) {                                #2#
    $chapter_number = $1;
    $chapter_number =~ tr/./_/;
}

# Skip if key found
next
  unless ( $sentence =~ /\b\Q$search_key\E/i                                  #3#
    && $sentence =~ /\b\Q$addkey0\E/i
    && $sentence =~ /\b\Q$addkey1\E/i );

# skip if excrescence 0 (or whatever exc is short for)
next
  if ( defined($exc0)                                                         #4#
    && length($exc0)
    && $sentence =~ /\b\Q$exc0\E\b/i );
# skip if excrescence 1.
next
  if ( defined($exc1)                                                         #5#
    && length($exc1)
    && $sentence =~ /\b\Q$exc1\E\b/i );
```

Now take these comments and make them into subs:

```
next unless is_sentence_block( $sent_block );

my( $sentence, $sentence_number ) = parse_sentence_block($sent_block);

# Maybe update the chapter number
my $new_chapter_number = get_chapter_number( $sentence );
$chapter_number = $new_chapter_number if defined $new_chapter_number;

next unless have_all_keys( $sentence => $search_key, $add_key0, $add_key1 ); 

next if have_excrescence( $exc0 );
next if have_excrescence( $exc1 );


sub is_sentence_block {
    my $block = shift;

    return $sent_block =~ /\[sent. \d+ len. \d+\]: \[.+\]/ );
}

sub get_chapter_number {
    my $sentence = shift;

    return unless $sentence =~ /\~\s(\d*F*[\.I_]\w+)\s/;
    return $1;
}

sub have_all_keys {
     my $sentence = shift;
     my @keys = @_;

     for my $key ( @keys ) { 
         return unless $sentence =~ /\b\Q$key1\E/i;
     }

     return 1
}

sub have_excrescence {
    my $sentence = shift;
    my $exc      = shift;

    return 0 unless defined($exc);
    return 0 unless length($exc)
    return 0 unless $sentence =~ /\b\Q$exc\E\b/i );

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Well, some good news: This works. So by testing each return, it works the same. I haven't been able to make a subroutine to encapsulate all of these subroutines yet ,but this is good enough I think.

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach (some of this code may look familiar to you ;-) ):

```
sub extractSentenceAndPositions {
    my $sentenceBlock = shift;
    my ($sentence, $sentenceNumber, $chapterNumber) = ("", "", "");

    if ($sentenceBlock =~ /\[sent. (\d+) len. \d+\]: \[(.+)\]/) {
        $sentenceNumber =  $1;
        $sentence       =  $2;
        $sentence       =~ s/, / /g;

        if ($sentence =~ /\~\s(\d*F*[\.I_]\w+)\s/) {                                   #2#
            $chapterNumber  =  $1;
            $chapterNumber  =~ tr/./_/;
        }

        # Turning the original 'next-unless' chain into a conditional
        # which zeroes out the return values instead
        if ( !( $sentence =~ /\b\Q$search_key\E/i                                      #3#
             && $sentence =~ /\b\Q$addkey0\E/i
             && $sentence =~ /\b\Q$addkey1\E/i )
            ||
             !( defined($exc0)                                                         #4#
             && length($exc0)
             && $sentence =~ /\b\Q$exc0\E\b/i )
            ||
             !( defined($exc1)                                                         #5#
             && length($exc1)
             && $sentence =~ /\b\Q$exc1\E\b/i )
           ) {
               ($sentence, $sentenceNumber, $chapterNumber) = ("", "", "");
        }
    }  

    return ($sentence, $sentenceNumber, $chapterNumber);
}
```

Then, replace your first listing with...

```
($sentence, $sentenceNumber, $chapterNumber) = extractSentenceAndPositions($sentblock);
next if (!$sentence || !$sentenceNumber || !$chapterNumber);
```

Regarding your best practices question, I would say for *this* use case (cgi vars and the like), where those values are almost certainly not going to change, I'd refer to them directly.  The basic concept I generally follow is to scrub them once at the beginning of the run (by which I mean sanitize away any SQL injections, XSS, XSRF, shell injections, or other such nastiness in the values) and from then on treat them as read-only globals.  I've heard other opinions on the subject, but that's what I usually do.

As far as checking the returned `$sentence` in the main program somehow destroying all the other matches, I'm not sure how that would happen unless there's something else going on.  I've used this approach (`next` or `last` based on returned values) in numerous scripts, and there's nothing inherently destructive about it.

Comment: I'm stumped, this looks like it'd work, however when I do it, it returns 0 matches (ie. if I omit the `next if (!$sen...)` it outputs blank, with a count of 1 match). So somehow the sentence is not being passed on. I would normally blame my regex or algorithm, but it works when it's outside of the subroutine!!

Comment: That's about the time I usually head into debug-land.  `print`s for everyone!  :-)  Seriously, a `print` before the call and a `print` after would probably not be a bad idea for starters.  What are the contents of all the `$sent*` variables before and after the sub call?  Going further, sprinkling `print`s through the sub to see what code paths it hits would also be valuable.  Sorry, without example data and/or some more code context there are quite a number of things that *might* be happening.  I can make lots of guesses, but I don't know that any of them would be intelligent.  :-)

Comment: That big load of logic makes we scared.  To understand it, I'd need a truth table.

Comment: Valid criticism.  I generally steer clear of such things.  I did it here only because it's a direct translation of (and equivalent to) the original `next-unless` chain referred to in the comment.  Ie - I felt it might make it a bit clearer how the transition from code-in-the-main-body to code-in-the-subroutine happened.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will definitely try and find where the hole is with some prints and 'debug-land'. Until then though, I'll just accept the broken-up version.